# If $E(X \mid A)\ge c$ and $E(X \mid B)\ge c$, then $E(X \mid A\cup B)\ge c$

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Let $A$ and $B$ be two disjoint events and $X$ any random variable with finite expectation. I have to prove that if $E(X \mid A)\ge c$ and $E(X \mid B)\ge c$, then $E(X \mid A\cup B)\ge c$.

We have

$$E(X \mid A\cup B)=\frac{\int_A X dP + \int_B X dP}{P(A)+P(B)}$$ but how can I go from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Use $$\frac{\int_A X \, d\mathbb{P}}{\mathbb{P}(A)+\mathbb{P}(B)} = \frac{\mathbb{P}(A)}{\mathbb{P}(A)+\mathbb{P}(B)} \underbrace{\frac{\int_A X \, d\mathbb{P}}{\mathbb{P}(A)}}_{\geq c} \geq c \frac{\mathbb{P}(A)}{\mathbb{P}(A) +\mathbb{P}(B)}$$ and the corresponding estimate for $\frac{\int_B X \, d\mathbb{P}}{\mathbb{P}(A)+\mathbb{P}(B)}$.

Comment: thanks, is assumption about finite expectation even needed here? what if $c$ is negative?

Comment: @ad233 If the expectation is not finite, then the integrals $\int_A X \, d\mathbb{P}$ and $\int_B X \, d\mathbb{P}$ are (in general) not well-defined. The estimate still works if $c$ is negative.

Answer (score 0):

Note that 
$$\int_A X\mathrm d\mathbb P\geqslant c\mathbb P(A);$$
the same bound holds when $A$ is replaced by $B$. Then take the sum.